# Issue with function not returning a vector

Tags: r, vector, append, return

I'm a newbie when it comes to 'R', but I've read up quite a bit of information and I still don't understand why I can't print the vector that i return in my function fn - I simply get the value "NULL". The goal of this function is to take values from two arrays, add them together and put them in a new array. I check with the print(test) command that the numbers in the arrays are being added correctly together which they are. Maybe I'm appending wrong? I don't see the problem right now.

```
fn <- function(x,y) {
liste <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 192)
k <- 0  
for (i in 1:(length(x))) {
    for (j in 1:(length(y))) {
        test<-x[i] + y[j]
        print(test)
        append(liste,test, after=k)
        k <- k +1
    }
}
return(liste)
}

event1 = c(0.0,5.0,10.0,12.0)
event2 = c(0.0,3.0,5.0,7.0)
event3 = c(6.0,8.0,10.0,10.0,12.0,13.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,17.0,20.0)

z <-fn(event2,event3)
names(z)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `z` is a vector (entirely of `0`s), it's just an unnamed vector. That's why `names(z)` returns `NULL`.

Secondly, in your approach, this line:

```
append(liste,test, after=k)
```

should simply be:

```
liste[k] = test
```

This is because `append` doesn't *change* the vectors that it is passed, it just returns a new one.

*However*, there is a *much* easier way to do what you're trying to do, using the `expand.grid` function:

```
fn <- function(x, y) {
    rowSums(expand.grid(x, y))
}
```

Comment: (+1) The last line is the actual answer. I was just writing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how I assign a return value to a variable then, if i cant do z<-fn(event2,event3)?

Comment: @John: that *does* assign a return value to a variable. Try printing `z` (*not* `names(z)`)